# How to determine options with gcc toolchain was built?

Tags: gcc, toolchain

I have a very old gcc toolchain and I would like to rebuild the new one with exactly same configuration options as the old one. Is there any way to determine the toolchain configuration assuming I do have only binary files of old toolchain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What configure options were used when building gcc / libstdc++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432133/what-configure-options-were-used-when-building-gcc-libstdc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "gcc -v":

> $ gcc -v
>
> Using built-in specs. Target: x86_64-linux-gnu Configured
>   with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro
>   4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1)