# How to get the options with which clang was compiled

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

It is possible to get gcc configure options with `gcc -v` (an example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432133/what-configure-options-were-used-when-building-gcc-libstdc)). Is there a similar way to retrieve the compilation options of clang?

My real task is the following one: I have an environment with a compiler (clang) which I want to improve. Now I have some patch for clang that I applied and I want to rebuild the patched sources, but I also want to be sure that nothing changes from the vanilla build apart from my patch; in particular, that all the build flags I use are the same.

Answer (score 1):

No, probably not. But it's possible to get the CXXFLAGS/LDFLAGS clang was compiled with via `llvm-config`.

```
$ llvm-config --cxxflags
-I/opt/compiler/llvm-trunk/include -march=native  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wcovered-switch-default -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS

$ llvm-config --ldflags
-L/opt/compiler/llvm-trunk/lib

$ llvm-config --system-libs
-lrt -ldl -lcurses -latomic -lpthread -lz -lm
```

If you are on a Linux distribution, then simply check the [PKGBUILD](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/llvm) (or similar) to find the exact flags.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a linux distribution, but the environment I modify is a custom-built one, so not PKGBUILD is available and I found no build script for that prebuilt clang so far.

Comment: @gluk47: Usually `./configure --enable-optimized --disable-assertions --path=<...>` is all you need.