# Cross compiling - Error: selected processor does not support `fmrx r3,fpexc' in ARM mode - Beaglebone

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, newlib

I'm trying to cross-compile a file to flash into the Beaglebone Black.
All works fine, but if I try to enable the FPU with

```
#define set_en_bit_in_fpexc() do { \
    int dummy; \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("fmrx %0,fpexc\n\t" \
                         "orr  %0,%0,#0x40000000\n\t" \
                         "fmxr fpexc,%0" : "=r" (dummy) : :); \
} while (0)
```

I get the following error

```
Error: selected processor does not support `fmrx r3,fpexc' in ARM mode
Error: selected processor does not support `fmxr fpexc,r3' in ARM mode
```

I also tried with `thumb mode`, but I get the same errors.
Of course if I remove the part of the code that initialize the FPU it works fine.

Why I get those errors?

**Makefile**

```
[...]
CROSSPATH?=/usr/bin
CROSSPFX=$(CROSSPATH)/arm-none-eabi-
CC=$(CROSSPFX)gcc
AS=$(CROSSPFX)as
LD=$(CROSSPFX)ld
NM=$(CROSSPFX)nm
OBJCOPY=$(CROSSPFX)objcopy
OBJDUMP=$(CROSSPFX)objdump
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O2 -ffreestanding
ARCHFLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a8 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon
CCARCHFLAGS=$(ARCHFLAGS) -marm
[...]
```

I'm on Arch, kernel 4.8.1

P.S. My professor uses the *linaro cross-compiler* and it works just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the Linaro toolchains are configured for ARMv7 hard-float by default (certainly the Linux ones, I'm less sure about the bare-metal ones). Looking at the configuration of the arm-none-eabi toolchain as packaged by Arch, I surmise it's just using the GCC defaults for things like that, which implies something like ARMv4t, and crucially, soft-float ABI.

Whilst the `-mfpu` option controls code generation in terms of which floating-point instructions may be used, apparently it's the float ABI which controls whether it'll let you do things which really *only* make sense on a hardware FPU, rather than under floating-point emulation.

When it's not configured by default, you need to explicitly select a floating-point ABI implying an actual hardware FPU, i.e. `-mfloat-abi=hard` (or `-mfloat-abi=softfp`, but there's really no reason to use that unless you need to link against other soft-float code).

Answer (score 1):

**`-mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard`**

Just to give a more direct solution, I had to add `-mfpu=vfpv3-d16`.

Test code `a.S`:

```
fmrx r2, fpscr
```

Working command:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabihf
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard a.S
```

Note that `-mfloat-abi=hard` is enabled by default on this particular build of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-as`, and could be omitted.

The default value of `float-abi` likely depends on `-msoft-float` vs `-mhard-float` controlled at GCC build time with:

```
./configure --with-float=soft
```

as documented at: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html You can get the flags used for your toolchain build with `gcc -v` as mentioned at: [What configure options were used when building gcc / libstdc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432133/what-configure-options-were-used-when-building-gcc-libstdc) I could not however easily determine its default value if not given.

You may also be interested in `-mfloat-abi=softfp` which can produce hard floats for the executable, but generate soft function calls: [ARM compilation error, VFP registered used by executable, not object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753749/arm-compilation-error-vfp-registered-used-by-executable-not-object-file)

The possible values of `-mfpu=` can be found at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options

Also note that FMRX is the pre-UAL syntax for VMRS which the newer recommended syntax, see also: [Are ARM instructuons SWI and SVC exactly same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459279/are-arm-instructuons-swi-and-svc-exactly-same-thing/54078731#54078731)

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, `arm-linux-gnueabihf-as` 2.26.1.