# How to compile c program as dll

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, dll

I finished working on my Checkers game engine and about to make it CheckerBoard (http://www.fierz.ch/cbdeveloper.php) compatible, and it states that.

> CheckerBoard expects your engine to be compiled as a dll and to be in
>   the working directory of checkerboard.exe - or in the path. An engine
>   must support 2 required functions. ..., you must provide 2 more
>   functions for multi-version support. The calling convention for all
>   functions is __stdcall().
>
> Required Functions
>
> The current CheckerBoard API (version 2) requires the following 2
>   functions:
>
> ```
> int WINAPI getmove(int board[8][8], int color, double maxtime, char str[1024], int *playnow, int info, int moreinfo, struct CBmove *move);
> int WINAPI enginecommand(char command[256], char reply[1024]);
> ```

my engine includes the two above functions, i've got everything setup (the code) but i'm having troubles compiling it as dll, heres what i tried (using gcc)

```
gcc -c engine.c
gcc -shared -o engine.dll engine.o
```

it creates the dll as expected but the dll doesn't export any of the functions (as expected).

I used the **Dependency walker** program to scan the engine.dll file, and it shows that the dll exports the functions

- _getmove@28
- _enginecommand@20

i scanned one of the engines in the CheckerBoard directory and i found that they export the following functions:

- getmove
- enginecommand

i cant figure out why the dll i created exports differently, maybe its got 
something to do with the **WINAPI** ?.

Any ideas ?

here's what it looks like

```
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT int WINAPI getmove(int b[8][8], int color, double time, char str[1024], int *playnow, int info, int unused, struct CBmove *cbmove){
    // ....
    return 0;
}


EXPORT int WINAPI enginecommand (char str[256], char reply[1024]){
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

i need both functions to be exported through the dll.

Comment: Please **edit your question** by giving some [MCVE], or at least by showing the relevant code (and declarations) in your `engine.c`; show the lines declaring and defining `getmove` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to annotate (the declaration of) these exported functions with [Windows function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Microsoft-Windows-Function-Attributes.html) like `__attribute__((dllexport))`; I recommend having a *declaration* like

```
extern WINAPI getmove(int b[8][8], int color, double time, 
                      char str[1024], int *playnow, int info, 
                      int unused, struct CBmove *cbmove) 
       __attribute__((dllexport));
```

before that function's definition.

You may need to compile your source as [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (on Linux it is nearly required with `-fPIC`, for Windows DLL you need to check your documentation).

So try to compile with `gcc -Wall -O -g -fPIC -shared engine.c -o engine.dll`

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/505567/841108) related question (and answers there).

<sup>PS. I never used Windows (only Unix since 1987 and Linux since 1993). I recommend reading Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book</sup>

Comment: Better improve your own question. By editing it and adding all the details, at least by giving the exact *declaration* of your exported functions in `engine.c` or by showing some [MCVE] related to your code